# Missing GAE's application to an existing Google API project

Tags: google-app-engine

The problem is the following:

> I have a Google API project which appears in Google API console and
>   Google Cloud console but not in App Engine's applications.

How can I add an App Engine's application to an existing Google API project?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't appear in the list of your GAE's apps, because it isn't a GAE app - it is just an API project.

You need to create a new GAE app, and you can do that from here:
https://appengine.google.com/

You can now use your GAE app with your API project, but I don't know of a way to actually associate your new GAE project with an existing API project.  They can be used together and technically associated, but the Cloud Console won't show them as associated.

If you didn't already have an API project then you could create your GAE app first and then create your API project from within your GAE app and then they would be fully associated.

Comment: Just one thing! When you create a GAE app, it's gonna create automatically an API project associated to that same GAE app with the same name!

That was before! when we create an GAE app and then, there was a button which would create an API project and associated the GAE project with the API project.

Comment: So, it should be possible to do the other way around! :) but i think it's not possible!

Comment: I agree, it should be possible do it the other way around, but it seems that it is not.